# TypeScript in Visual Studio Online Build

Tags: typescript, tfsbuild, azure-devops, typescript1.5, typescript1.4

I'm trying to set up CI using VisualStudio.com hosted build for an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 project that uses the new TypeScript 1.5 tools during build. I've set up my CI build definition with the new non-XAML build definition format.

I get the following error when trying to build:

> ##[error](103,5): Error : Your project file uses a different version of the TypeScript compiler and tools than is currently installed on this machine.  No compiler was found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.5\1.5\tsc.exe.  You may be able to fix this problem by changing the  element in your project file.

What looks odd to me is the extra 1.5 subfolder underneath the 1.5 folder. That is incorrect: the standard install location for tsc.exe is at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.5\tsc.exe".

Note that I have also tried reverting this to use 1.4, and I get the same error: the path is ...TypeScript\1.4\1.4\tsc.exe in the logs.

I am not referencing tsc.exe directly. Below are the only TypeScript references in my csproj:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
```

and

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

My gut tells me that TypeScript 1.5 is actually installed because I see other references to .NET 4.6 in the build logs (both released as part of VS2015), but that the path is incorrect. And I'm pretty certain that TS 1.4 is installed.

I see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142996/how-to-edit-the-typescript-1-4-specified-task-executable-location) that seems to have the same issue with the duplicate sub-folder, but obviously I can't do any of the suggested fixes to the VSO hosted build agent.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug with the new non-XAML VSO Hosted Build?

Comment: I have the same issue, even removing `TypeScriptToolsVersion` from .csproj file doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, seems the answer is simple. It's a bug in [VSO build controllers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/archive/2015/07/27/type-script-issues-with-visual-studio-online-build-controllers-7-27-investigating.aspx)

> We are actively investigating issues with TypeScript errors on Visual Studio Online hosted build service. Some customers may experience an error about “…TypeScript\1.4\1.4\tsc.exe" is invalid. This webpage gives more information of this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3493
>   We are applying the workaround to the targets file on the VM and it will be updated in next few hours.

Comment: I can confirm that this is working for me now, they have fixed the issue.