# Windows 10 tsc error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, windows-10, typescript1.6

After moving to fresh windows 10 PC i have stuck with error.

```
TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: tsconfig.json
```

tsc stop working with tsconfig.json, i can not force it to find tsconfig.json, i call it with --p/--project flag and specify full path - nothing helped.

Where is a problem? And how it can be solved?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.js
```

for some reason the typescript was installed separately (not via npm) there, and that exe file replaced new one from npm.

i removed that folder ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript") and problem was fixed.

Comment: or remove the folder from your path environment

Comment: Worked for me. I just deleted the entire folder, restarted VS Code, and bam, tsc now working from the terminal

Comment: I somehow got around 5 different versions of TypeScript inside Microsoft SDKs directory and after deleting TypeScript is ran perfectly fine. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and found that I have two typescript versions (1.0 and 1.8) in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`

After removing the old version, it continued working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's answer in the following stackoverflow post fixed it for me:

[How to edit the Typescript 1.4 "specified task executable location"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142996/how-to-edit-the-typescript-1-4-specified-task-executable-location)

I'll post what he said here in case anything happens to it but please up-vote his post if it helped you!

Basically what Kevin said was go to the following places and rename (or if you have balls of steel you can delete) the "typescript" folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\

**after that run a repair on your visual studio 2015 installation.**

so the accepted answer in this question came close to fixing my problem, but not all the way :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem. When I verified the version of the TypeScript (TS) compiler (tsc -v) it showed as 1.0. I have other latest versions of TS since I had multiple Visual Studio versions installed. I checked the path environment  variable (in Windows) and the path to TS was set. I removed the path of TS 1.0  from the path environment variable. Once it is removed, TS installation is pointing to the latest installation if any (same as tsc -v) as I have installed through npm. Or, try re-installing TS using npm (npm install typescript -g). Now it should point to the latest and work as you expected.